# array contain the string

Tags: java, android

I have the  array in **Arrays.xml**

```
<string-array name="text_language">
    <item> English</item>
    <item> Russian</item>
</string-array>
```

How can I check, array contain the string (for example from `EditText`)?

Maybe,

```
 if(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text_language).contains(" "));
```

does not work.

Comment: use .isEmpty(); may be it will work

Comment: Lol ... to *check, array contain the string* you have to: "check size of array" or "use .isEmpty();" or "use array.length==0 " ... guys do you read the question?

Comment: USe like that getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text_language).length==0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works perfect:

```
String[] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
List<String> mList = Arrays.asList(myArray );
if(mList .contains("your_value")){
   System.out.println("String Exists");
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It is work for me

Answer (score 0):

Same as MeosCoder, but here .`equals()` instead of `contains()`

As `contains()` will return a part of matched string, we should `.equals()` to properly find the data whether its available or not.

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourarray);
for (String data: array) {
    if (data.equals(your_data)) {
        //data is there
    }else{
        //your_data is not in array
    }
}
```